# Shiny app only works after touching ui.R inside Docker container

Tags: r, docker, shiny, shiny-server

I'm witnessing a strange phenomenon with an R Shiny demo app ("used-space") I hacked together. It only consists of a data table, filled with some random data. Here's the code:

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
        dataTableOutput("foobar")
    )
)
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

source("data-generator.R")

data <- randomEntries(100) # function from data-generator.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    cols <- c("First Name", "Last Name", "ID", "Disk Usage")
    output$foobar <- renderDataTable(expr=data, colnames=cols)
})
```

Everything works perfectly when started from RStudio with `runApp()`.

Now I want to run it in a Docker container. Don't hesitate on pointing out the things I'm doing wrong, I just got started with Docker, and getting the permissions right (or working, at least) was quite a hassle.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos
MAINTAINER Patrick Bucher "patrick.bucher@compa.ny"

RUN ["rpm", "-Uvh", "https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm"]
RUN ["yum", "-y", "install", "R", "wget", "git"]

RUN ["R", "-e", "install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"]
RUN ["R", "-e", "install.packages('rmarkdown', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"]
RUN ["R", "-e", "install.packages('DT', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"]
RUN ["wget", "https://download3.rstudio.org/centos5.9/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.3.838-rh5-x86_64.rpm"]
RUN ["yum", "-y", "install", "--nogpgcheck", "shiny-server-1.5.3.838-rh5-x86_64.rpm"]
RUN ["rm",  "shiny-server-1.5.3.838-rh5-x86_64.rpm"]

RUN ["yum", "clean", "all"]

RUN ["mkdir", "-p", "/srv/shiny-server"]
RUN ["mkdir", "-p", "/var/log/shiny-server"]
RUN ["mkdir", "-p", "/var/lib/shiny-server"]

RUN ["ln", "-fs", "/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Zurich", "/etc/localtime"]

COPY start-shiny /usr/bin/start-shiny

EXPOSE 3838
```

build:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p apps
mkdir -p logs

rm -rf apps/used-space

docker build -t shinysrv
```

run:

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3838 -j ACCEPT

DIRS[0]=/srv/shiny-server
DIRS[1]=/var/log/shiny-server
DIRS[2]=/var/lib/shiny-server

docker run --privileged --name ssrv01 -dit -p 3838:3838 -v `pwd`/apps:${DIRS[0]} -v `pwd`/logs:${DIRS[1]} shinysrv sh

for DIR in ${DIRS[@]}; do
    docker exec --privileged ssrv01 chown -R shiny:shiny $DIR
    docker exec --privileged ssrv01 chmod -R 755 $DIR
done

docker exec --user shiny ssrv01 start-shiny
```

start-shiny:

```
#!/bin/sh

git clone https://github.com/patrickbucher/used-space.git /srv/shiny-server/used-space
exec shiny-server 1> /tmp/shiny.out 2> /tmp/shiny.err &
```

connect:

```
#!/bin/sh

docker exec --user shiny -it ssrv01 sh
```

Everything works fine, the server is coming up. But when I go to localhost:3838/used-space, I see a blank page. Now comes the fun part: I just open the shell (`./connect`) and run `touch /srv/shiny-server/used-space/ui.R`, load the page again -- and it works perfectly well.

My feeling says that this is related to Docker layers, but I can't point out what is "wrong" with it. Could anybody do? (I tried it out on two configurations: once on an Arch Linux host system, once on a CentOS virtual system, hosted on Windows 10 using VirtualBox. The behaviour was exactly the same. When I `touch` another file, say `server.R`, it doesn't start to work.)

Comment: Can give this as a git repo?

Comment: Docker: https://github.com/patrickbucher/shinysrv

Comment: App: https://github.com/patrickbucher/used-space

Comment: Now it's getting even weirder! I added other GUI components, and they all appear straight from the beginning, but not the data table. After I `touch` ui.R, the data table also appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. The ui.R was missing `library(DT)`, so the data table could not be built up. ui.R is probably loaded before server.R, which loads the DT library. When I executed `touch` on ui.R, the server reloaded and freshly executed it, now having the DT library loaded correctly. It works now!